# Calculate the volume (double or triple integral) with boundaries

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Suppose we have the following boundaries:

$x^2+y^2 \le a^2$

$x \ge 0$

$y \ge 0$

$0 \le z \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

I need to calculate the volume of the figure which is bounded by these conditions. So I know that the most obvious way would be to use a triple integral with the following boundaries:

$$ \int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{dzdydx}$$

However, after solving the first integral I get $$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dydx}$$

but the next integral seems kinda hard to solve which makes me wonder if the volume should be calculated by another method (for example a substitution).

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered cylindrical coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done that way, but it's hard. It's better to do it in cylindrical coordinates, in which case your integral becomes$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^a\int_0^rr\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{\pi a^3}6.$$

Comment: I did but I have trouble with the boundaries. For example, if $x=rcos{\theta}$, $y=rsin{\theta}$, $z=z$, $ 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$, if I plugged this in I would get:
$r \le a^2$, $\cos{\theta} \ge 0$ and $\sin{\theta} \ge 0 $ which is the first quadrant.

thus I don't know how your boundaries for $\theta$ are $0$ and $r$, and the same goes for $z$! My $z$ boundaries are $0, r$

Comment: Since $r\cos(\theta)=x\geqslant0$ and $r\sin(\theta)=y\geqslant0$, $\theta\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$. Asserting that $x^2+y^2\leqslant a^2$ is the same thing as asserting that $r\leqslant a$. Finally, asserting that $0\leqslant z\leqslant\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the same thing as asserting that $0\leqslant z\leqslant r$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Thanks!